# Android - How to make keyboard come up on EditText

Tags: android-softkeyboard, android

I have a view with an `editText` but the keyboard doesn't show up. After lots of research the only suitable thing I could find was how to make the keyboard appear when first loading the view. However, if the user closes the keyboard it seems there is no way to get it back.

How can I make the keyboard appear every time the user enters the `editText` field?

Comment: doesn't it appears when you click on the editText ?

Comment: If the user click on the EditText the keyboard will show automatically. If the user decide to hide the keyboard then this is their decision. You should not force the users to do what you want them to do

Comment: It doesn't come up automatically for me, this is weird, why wouldnt it?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you click in the EditText box to type the text, then android keyboard automatically open.